Azure Data Factory pipeline not executing on all the string-values put into the parameter-array
I have a pipeline within Azure with the purpose of updating my Power BI-reports automatically from my MSSQL-database. The pipeline currently updates three power bi-reports, which reports to update is specified in the parameters of the pipeline, with a string within an array. The string is the endpoint to the semantic model of the Power BI-report that I am trying to update: Similar to below:
["xxxxxxx-36je-4164-xxxxxxx","xxxxxxx-e8j5-4477-a960-xxxxxxx","xxxxxxx-e88f-459d-8fc8-xxxxxxx","xxxxxxx-f6b9-47fb-a81e-xxxxxxx"]

The first three reports has been working fine for some time. I am now trying to add the fourth report to automatically update, but I can't for my life figure out why it wont update.
I have tried adding the endpoint of the power bi semantic model I am trying to update, it works fine in debug mode. But after publishing the changes to the pipeline, the report doesn't update. The three original reports are however still updating.
Did any of you come across a similar issue? It feels like a bug in Azure, since the debug mode works fine and updates everything perfectly. Below is a image of my pipeline (with the parameters removed).
My pipeline: (https://i.sstatic.net/eJVdf2vI.png)

How do you pass the value to the parameter pbi_datasets after publishing? perhaps the value comes from a trigger, and you haven't updated that value to include the last dataset.

@ChenHirsh thanks for your reply. I pass the parameters statically. The idea is that whenever the pipeline runs, the same power bi-reports should be updated. You can see in my image how they are passed.
I looked into it and all the triggers are also updated with the correct power bi endpoints. Thanks for your effort!

my point was that the default value in your pipeline is not the value the pipeline runs with on trigger. Just check in the monitor what was the parameter value in the actual run.

As Chen Harish said, if you are running your pipeline using trigger, you need to update the trigger parameters also. Below are the steps to do.
- Click the trigger button in the pipeline.
- Click New/Edit.
- Click the associated trigger name and change the parameters as given in the below gif.

- Make sure to publish the pipeline.

@Johannes  Check if above provided solution works for you?
